# How to access an update value from within an update statement in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update, prepared-statement

I am trying to do something like that in a prepared statement:

```
UPDATE table SET active = ?, last_action = IF(VALUES(active) > 0, NOW(), last_action) WHERE id = ?
```

So I am trying to access the value I am setting with SET active = ? in the same query.

However VALUES(active) does not seem to represent the value of active = ?
Is there any way to make this work like it would when the values are part of an INSERT INTO [...] VALUES [...] ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... statement?

Possible solution: add another parameter like this: IF(? > 0, NOW(), last_action) and set it to the same value as the active = ? parameter.

Is there any better solution that does not require me to bind the same value to another parameter?

Comment: what's the problem with binding the same value?

Comment: Nothing really, but I thought if INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE provides this functionality there might be a similar one in simple UPDATE statements as well.

Comment: the best source for such an information (if this situation bugs you so much) is mysql manual for UPDATE statement. Whatever helper functions they have, are listed there, I believe.

Comment: Since I did not find a word about using VALUES in ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE on the MySQL page for INSERT, I thought there might be some similar construct for UPDATE. (I know that there is an extra page for INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE)